# I want to copy files from temporary folder to in my c drive by creating new folder

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

```
if FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SPECTRUMJOBS_Data.MDF'), 
     ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.LOGISTICS\MSSQL\DATA\SPECTRUMJOBS_Data.MDF'), 
     False) then
```

I tried the above one but I am not able to copy because there is no folder named **DATA** in the location.

so please help me to copy the DATA folder and the file

Comment: in inno setup i am not able to do this please help me

Comment: Your comment indicates that your question is about Inno Setup. For future reference, you can edit your question by a click on the "edit" button just below the tags. All relevant details must be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered yourself. If there is no folder DATA in folder MSSQL, the folder must be created first.
And... if there is no folder MSSQL in folder MSSQL11.LOGISTICS, that folder must be created first.
And so on...
Now read the above sentences in reverse order, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you so much actually there is no files in the source folder . now i understood the concept.

Answer (score 3):

To force creation of directories you can use (text is from InnoSetup help):

> **Prototype:**
>
> function ForceDirectories(Dir: string): Boolean;
>
> **Description:**
>
> Creates all the directories along the specified directory
> path all at once. If the first directories in the path do exist, but
> the latter ones don't, ForceDirectories creates just the ones that
> don't exist. Returns True if successful, False otherwise.

InnoSetup documentation is at [ishelp](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)

Comment: For future reference, you can edit the question to add tags you notice were omitted when reading the post. :-) Also, your info for the OP regarding editing should be in a comment to the question itself, rather than in your answer.